# Completely hiding a dir, but leaving its descendants accessible via symlinks, in Samba

Tags: network-shares, samba, freebsd, acl, access-control

Due to the way Samba handles symlinks and wide links (it can only distinguish "within the share root" or "outside the share root") I want to create fixed symlinks in the share root to the "actual" dirs, and then prevent the "actual" dirs being shown directly to the user when they browse the network share, as shown.

Is this possible?

**ACTUAL STRUCTURE (FreeBSD file server):**

```
share_root
   --- data1
          --- data3
          --- data4
          --- data5
          --- data6
   --- data2
          --- data7
          --- data8
          --- data9
   --- d4 (=symlink to data4)
   --- d6 (=symlink to data6)
   --- d9 (=symlink to data9)
```

**WHAT THE USER SEES (Windows client):**

```
share_root
   --- d4 (and all data4's subdirs)
   --- d6 (and all data6's subdirs)
   --- d9 (and all data9's subdirs)

   (note: actual access to any dir is controlled by ACLs on data1/data2
    and their subdirs, so this just cleans up the tree seen by a user
    when they browse the share; it doesn't create any security)
```

Essentially the "real" dirs data1/data2 contain a mix of dirs the user can/can't access, and that access is enforced by ACLs.

But when the user accesses the share, I want them to not see these dirs in the first place.

"Normal" hidden files will be shown in Windows Explorer so I can't use "hide files" or dot-files to do this. I could use other methods such as veto files, access-controlled enumeration, ACL read/traverse, and so on if they help. However I only want to prevent data1/data2 being shown directly to the user - I don't want to kill traversal **via symlinks d4/d6/d9** to subdirs of data1/data2.

Is this possible using a combination of access controlled enumeration, smb.conf and ACLs? If not, what would get me closest to a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your request completely, but using `nullfs` mounts is the first tactic that springs to mind.

Leave the physical, actual structure alone.  Call it `physical_root` for the sake of this example.

Make a new empty directory for the `share_root`, and point Samba to it in your smb4.conf.

Under the `share_root`, create mountpoints for all the directories you want to expose to Samba clients:

```
for DIR in d4 d6 d9; do
    mkdir /share_root/$DIR
done
```

Now null-mount the actual, physical directories into the phony `share_root` space:

```
mount_nullfs /physical_root/data1/data4 /share_root/d4
mount_nullfs /physical_root/data1/data6 /share_root/d6
mount_nullfs /physical_root/data2/data9 /share_root/d9
```

Those mounts can be added to /etc/fstab, probably using the 'late' option:

```
/physical_root/data1/data4  /share_root/d4  nullfs  rw,late  0  0
...etc...
```